# Meteor Blaze iterate over dynamically created object

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to iterate with Blaze over dynamically created object. I have the collection and the object, but I can't display the data in my tables and I don't understand why.

Here's my code to retrieve the object :

In my Template Helpers :

```
fields: ()=> {
    var collectionSelected = FlowRouter.current().params.collectionName;

    // var data = Mongo.Collection.get(collectionSelected).find().count();


    var collectionObject = Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected});

    console.log(Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected}));

    return Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected});
},

values: ()=> {

    var collectionSelected = FlowRouter.getParam('collectionName');
    var collectionObject = Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected});
    var dataArray = [];

    var data = Meteor.call('findElmt', collectionSelected, function(err, res){
        console.log('VALUES : ');
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    });

},
```

The findElmt method :

```
findElmt(collectionName){
    if (global.hasOwnProperty(collectionName)){
        var res = Mongo.Collection.get(collectionName).find().fetch();

        console.log(res);
        return res;
    }

    else {
        global[collectionName] = new Meteor.Collection(collectionName);

        var res = Mongo.Collection.get(collectionName).find().fetch();
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    }

}
```

And finally the way I'm trying to display it with Blaze :

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    {{#with fields}}
        {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
            <thead>
                <tr>
                {{#each fields.fieldsName}}
                    <th data-sortable="true">{{this}}</th>
                {{/each}}
                </tr>
            </thead>
        {{else}}
            <p>Loading...</p>
        {{/if}}
    {{/with}}
    <tbody>
        {{#each values}}
            <tr>
            {{#each valueString in values.items}}
                <td>{{valueString}}</td>
            {{/each}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have any advice on what I'm doing wrong, thank you !

EDIT 1 : I added the fields helper !

Comment: Can you please add the `helpers` from the template, especially `fields`?

Comment: I added it in the helpers code

Comment: Is your Method returning values ? Or you only have a problem to show them ? What's the structure of your returned values. And what is printing with the following:  `console.log('VALUES : ');console.log(res);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you a lot for your help, I finally nailed it.

Here's the final code for the future lost soul like me !

Template Helpers :

```
fields: ()=> {
    var collectionSelected = FlowRouter.current().params.collectionName;

    // var data = Mongo.Collection.get(collectionSelected).find().count();


    var collectionObject = Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected});

    console.log(Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected}));

    return Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected});
},

values: ()=> {

    var collectionSelected = FlowRouter.getParam('collectionName');
    var collectionObject = Collections.findOne({name: collectionSelected});
    var dataArray = [];

    console.log(ReactiveMethod.call("findElmt", collectionSelected));

    return ReactiveMethod.call("findElmt", collectionSelected);
}
```

The server side FindElmt method didn't change,
and finally the Blaze code :

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
                    {{#with fields}}
                        {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                {{#each fields.fieldsName}}
                                    <th data-sortable="true">{{this}}</th>
                                {{else}}
                                    {{! will this fix this issue? }}
                                {{/each}}
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        {{else}}
                            <p>Loading...</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    {{else}}
                        {{! will this fix this issue? }}
                    {{/with}}

                    {{#with values}}
                        <tbody>
                        {{#each values}}
                            <tr>
                            {{#each valueString in this.items}}
                                <td>{{valueString}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                                {{! will this fix this issue? }}
                            {{/each}}
                            </tr>
                        {{else}}
                            {{! will this fix this issue? }}
                        {{/each}}
                        </tbody>
                    {{else}}
                        {{! will this fix this issue? }}
                    {{/with}}

                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `values` is an array of JsonObject with the field `items`, you are iterating the wrong way.
When using `{{#each}}` and not `{{#each in}}` you can access directly your properties with `items`or with `this.items`.

If `values` is an array of JsonObject :

```
<tbody>
    {{#each values}}
        <tr>
        {{#each valueString in this.items}} // values.items -> this.items
            <td>{{valueString}}</td>
        {{/each}}
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

If `values` is a JsonObject, you can use `with` :

```
<tbody>
    {{#with values}}
        <tr>
        {{#each valueString in this.items}} // values.items -> this.items
            <td>{{valueString}}</td>
        {{/each}}
        </tr>
    {{/with}}
</tbody>
```

Then to have a reactive returned value with Method call you can use the following package :
https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method

Comment: Values is a JsonObject, but items is an array in the object containing the values of the object (hope it sounds clear).

Comment: Please show me the structure like this way, i understand it like that : `values = [{items:["myString1", "myString2"]}, {items:["myString1", "myString2"]}]`. And for what i see in your code, values is not a JsonObject but an array of JsonObject because `.find().fetch()` is returning an array. And so did you tried my code above ?

Comment: Object exemple : { "_id" : "mqSdDHpLf3EEEe7HJ", "thyt" : "7", "items" : [ "7", "8", "9" ], "ezez" : "8", "zareza" : "9" }

Comment: I edited my answer to work with a JsonObject. But are you sure you are receiving your data ? Are your console.log showing your data ?

Comment: Yes I have a console.log on my data showing me my data. So I retrieve it but can't use it ... :/

Comment: Ok ! I understand so you have two problem, first one: use this package: https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method and second: use my code to show the data.